# Why does "tag info" list hot answers, not hot questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, hot-questions, hot-answers

If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/hot , you get a list of hot answers, not hot questions. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info includes several tabs that show questions:

[image]

Your second link comes from the side bar:

[image]

So, basically... it's just another view, showing answers on purpose because why not? Answers deserve some love too.